# Confused about mysql compsite index and leftmost prefix matching

Tags: mysql, indexing, composite-index

My MySQL version is 5.7 and I created a test table with 1,332,660 records:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`data_name` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
`data_time` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`data_value` decimal(50,8) DEFAULT NULL,
`data_code` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`create_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `idx_name_time_value` (`data_name`,`data_time`,`data_value`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

there is  an index by`data_name`,`data_time`,`data_value`.
I have three SQL and there results :

```
explain select  *  from test    where data_name ='abc' and  data_time = '2022-06-15 00:00:00' and data_value=75.1
```

[image]

```
explain select  *  from test    where   data_time = '2022-06-15 00:00:00' and data_value=75.1
```

[image]

```
explain select  data_name  from test    where   data_time = '2022-06-15 00:00:00' and data_value=75.1
```

[image]

According to the `leftmost prefix matching` the second sql does not use index, but the third one actually used an index.

My question is why can the thired sql use index, and why does a full table scan occur even when indexes are used (The seconde one's Explain result `rows` is equal to the thired one's `rows`).

Can someone help me ? Thans a lot!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query 3 -- Why it uses the index but is slow...

```
select  data_name
    from  test
    where  data_time = '2022-06-15 00:00:00'
      and  data_value=75.1
```

needs 3 columns, and all are in a single index.  So using that index is probably faster than scanning the table.  This is called a "covering index".  It is indicated in `EXPLAIN` with `Using index`.  "Leftmost" is not relevant; "covering" is.

Still, it will have to scan the entire index, as indicated by "Rows" being approximately the number of rows in the table.

Your datetime string looks like MySQL's datetime; it would be better to declare the column `DATETIME` instead of `VARCHAR`.

Query 1 is likely to be fast since you are testing all 3 columns of the index with `=`.

Query 2 is likely to be very slow since the columns in the `WHERE` are not "leftmost".

```
select  *
    from  test
    where  data_time = '2022-06-15 00:00:00'
      and  data_value=75.1
```

would benefit *either of these*:

```
INDEX(data_time, data_value)
INDEX(data_value, data_time)
```

Query 4:

```
    where  data_name ='abc'
      and  data_time = '2022-06-15 00:00:00'
      and  data_value >= 75
      and  data_value <  76
```

This will be fast because "leftmost" lets the index be used.

Query 5:

```
    where  data_name ='abc'
      and  data_time >= '2022-06-15'
      and  data_value = 75.1
```

This will be only somewhat fast because "leftmost" will stop with the `data_time`.  That is, it stopped after the *first* "range" test.  Adding this would make query 5 fast and fully use the index:

```
   INDEX(data_name, data_value,   -- tested with "="
         data_time)               -- tested with "range"
```

Note that the order of columns in the index important; the order of tests in `WHERE` is not.